# What tool can be used to change the orientation of a pdf page without using the `Rotate` key value?

Tags: pdf, pdftk

On page 78 of the [PDF Specification 2008](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf), it mentions that the PDF's page object has an integer key value `Rotate` that you can set to tell the software how the page should be displayed. This value shall be multiple of 90 degrees.
[image]

So a lot of tools would simply rotate the pdf page by simply setting this key and leave the original page content untouched. I am wondering if there is a way to change orientation of the page by modifying the actual page stored in pdf directly, instead of doing this marker-style modification?

So what I am trying to achieve here is:

Rotate the page (say) 90 degrees physically instead of simply setting the `Rotate` key value to 90. (That's to say the value of `Rotate` should remain 0 after rotation.)

Any command line tools can be used here? I have tried the `pdftk`, but it only sets the `Rotation` key.

Comment: You can use `mutool` to decompress streams, edit with a text editor and modify the transformation matrix for the page using the Postscript commands, then compress and fix the xref. I wouldn't be surprised if there are command line tools that already do that for you, but in general it can be difficult depending on how the page is drawn (blindly inserting a transformation won't always work).

Comment: You might look at converting the pdf to PostScript (eg with `pdf2ps`) then using tools like `pstops` from `psutils` to rotate the page using the page matrix.

Comment: For others coming here to achieve the rotation without modifying the page data to achieve it, you can use `qpdf --rotate=270:1 original.pdf rotated.pdf` (where `270` in this case is the angle in degrees and could be 90, 180 or 270 depending on the desired outcome).

Comment: I am working on https://github.com/WolfgangFahl/nicepdf using PyPDF to eg. "un-booklet" scanned double page A5 documents to A4 where this function is needed